# Reduce function to return a string

Tags: javascript, reduce

The following is instruction to the code (for now my code keeps returning undefined): 
Use the reduce function to iterate through an array of words and construct a decoded sentence (string) based on the following criteria:
If the array element is exactly three characters in length, add a space character to your accumulator
Otherwise, capitalize the LAST character of the array element and add it to your accumulator

```
function decode(sentence) {
    let words = sentence.split(' ');
    let newWords = words.reduce(function(acc,word){
        if (word.length < 3) {
            acc += ' ';
            console.log(acc);
        }
        else {
            acc += (word[word.length-1].toUpperCase());
            console.log(acc);
        }
    }, '');
    return newWords;
}

console.log(decode('noggin oreo the moon time tele steed his tent apollo her lives though shoo tofu budapest'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You aren't returning the accumulator inside the predicate:

```
let newWords = words.reduce(function(acc, word) {
    if (word.length < 3) {
        acc += ' ';
        console.log(acc);
    } else {
        acc += word[word.length - 1].toUpperCase();
        console.log(acc);
    }
    return acc;
}, '');
```

Since you don't return the accumulator, every time the predicate is called, you'll get undefined as the accumulator for the next predicate call.

Comment: I almost down-voted this answer because the instructions specifiy to make a space char when the element is EXACTLY three characters long. Your line should be: `if (word.length === 3) {`. Please fix your code.